# TFS 2012 to 2013 Upgrade + domain change advice needed

Tags: tfs, active-directory, domaincontroller

We're going to upgrade our TFS 2012 to TFS 2013 in the coming month - which also means we're going to update our SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster to 2012.

Furthermore - our TFS is currently hosted in a different domain from our company default domain and we want to change that to our company default domain so it can just run under our 'normal' domain controller.

So that gives us 2 possible paths for the upgrade:

1. In place upgrade - then [migrate to the new domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx)
2. Set up a whole new environment in the new domain, and then move the old TFS to the new. This seems to [be kind-of a backup-restore
   operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms404869.aspx).

My question is: what's the recommended way - what would cause the least pain?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access your `Windows Server` and launch `Server Manager dashboard` and select your Role and Features.
On your `domain controller` you have possibility to `attach specific domain to your target domain`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, from what I understand that allows me to connect the server to a differernt AD controller - but what strategy would you recommend to use? In-place upgrade, or migration?

Comment: Happy to help you, migration it's easy with platform migration